# .sendto() method on sikuli python script does not work on windows

Tags: python, sockets, jython, sikuli, sendto

I developed a sikuli python script on windows that uses this code:

```
from socket import AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
import sys
import socket
import struct, time

host = "pool.ntp.org"
port = 123
buf = 1024
address = (host,port)
msg = '\x1b' + 47 * '\0'

# reference time (in seconds since 1900-01-01 00:00:00)
TIME1970 = 2208988800L # 1970-01-01 00:00:00

# connect to server
client = socket.socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
client.sendto(msg, address)
msg, address = client.recvfrom( buf )

t = struct.unpack( "!12I", msg )[10]
t -= TIME1970

current_time = time.ctime(t).replace(" "," ")
```

The code is working fine under linux or in a python script on windows, but if I use this code on sikulix on windows it crashes (at line => **client.sendto(msg, address)** ) with the following error:

```
[error] script [ Sikuli_Test_Original ] stopped with error in line 23
[error] _socket.error ( [Errno -1] Unmapped exception:     java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: event executor terminated )
[error] --- Traceback --- error source first line: module ( function ) statement 359: _socket ( handle_exception ) _socket.error: [Errno -1] Unmapped exception: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: event executor terminated
995: _socket ( sendto ) File "C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Sikuli\sikulix.jar\Lib\_socket.py", line 971, in _datagram_connect
[error] --- Traceback --- end --------------
```

Any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: From the error logs I had the impression that sikuli tried to use its own _socket.py and not the system one

Comment: Are you using same sikuli version on both systems?

Comment: yes, the latest version of sikulix

Comment: Then problem is with Jython as such. Because sikuli uses Jython in background. Then only workaround would be to use `run()` function in sikuli and run the python file as external script.

Comment: can you confirm system requirements are full filled https://github.com/kevlened/sikuli_cpython#requirements

Comment: These requirements are for? In my windows I installed Python 2.7 and the latest sikulix.

Comment: using scapy can work for you?
I ask if to try write something with scapy

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was discussed and apparently solved in this thread discussing how Sikuli interops with Jython (and it seems like a Jython bug): https://bugs.launchpad.net/sikuli/+bug/1464105

I checked the solution; this code works for me on Windows 10 from within the SikuliX IDE. The trick in basically in the added initialization header at the top:

```
import sys, _socket
from socket import AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM
if _socket.NIO_GROUP.isShutdown():
    print "RE-CREATING NIO_GROUP"
    _socket.NIO_GROUP = _socket.NioEventLoopGroup(2, _socket.DaemonThreadFactory("PyScan-Netty-Client-%s"))
    sys.registerCloser(_socket._shutdown_threadpool)
import socket
import struct, time

host = "pool.ntp.org"
port = 123
buf = 1024
address = (host,port)
msg = '\x1b' + 47 * '\0'

# reference time (in seconds since 1900-01-01 00:00:00)
TIME1970 = 2208988800L # 1970-01-01 00:00:00
print "Before socket operation"
# connect to server
client = socket.socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
client.sendto(msg, address)
print "After socket operation"
msg, address = client.recvfrom( buf )
t = struct.unpack( "!12I", msg )[10]
t -= TIME1970

current_time = time.ctime(t).replace(" "," ")
print current_time
```